# ms access 2003 update query sql not working properly

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

the query is this :

UPDATE ParametersMain2 INNER JOIN ParametersMain 
ON ParametersMain2.VMV_CODE=ParametersMain.VMV_CODE 
SET ParametersMain2.PARENT_VARIABLE_NAME=ParametersMain.PARENT_VARIABLE_NAME
AND ParametersMain2.VARIABLE_NAME=ParametersMain.VARIABLE_NAME;

Each time it says all the entries are being updated. each time i go look. the PARENT_VARIABLE_NAME fields and VARIABLE_NAME fields are still blank in ParametersMain2.
and the entire column of those fields are filled in in ParametersMain

why isntit working? i checked to see that its all the same data types and formats between the two tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap the AND with a comma, as below.

```
UPDATE 
    ParametersMain2 

        INNER JOIN 
    ParametersMain 
        ON ParametersMain2.VMV_CODE = ParametersMain.VMV_CODE
SET 
    ParametersMain2.PARENT_VARIABLE_NAME = ParametersMain.PARENT_VARIABLE_NAME , 
    ParametersMain2.VARIABLE_NAME = ParametersMain.VARIABLE_NAME;
```

AND is operator that combines booleans (and nulls), if you want to set multiple fields separate them with a comma.

Comment: "AND is a boolean operator" -- not really e.g. `1 AND NULL` evaluates to UNKNOWN and three-valued logic is not Boolean!

Comment: @onedaywhen, agreed, I'll tweak.